# Inserting a different cell object into IndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a list of custom cells (cell A's).  I'd like to insert a different cell type (cell B) into the model's `indexPath` at the `nth` row. However, I am using dynamic extensions to create my models.

Here is my `dataSource` code;

```
class HomeViewDataSource<Model, Cell: UITableViewCell>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

typealias CellConfigurator = (Model, Cell) -> Void

var models: [Model]

private let reuseIdentifier: String
private let cellConfigurator: CellConfigurator

init(models: [Model], reuseIdentifier: String, cellConfigurator: @escaping CellConfigurator) {
    self.models = models
    self.reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier
    self.cellConfigurator = cellConfigurator
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return models.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let model = models[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as! Cell
    cellConfigurator(model, cell)
    return cell
    }
}

extension HomeViewDataSource where Model == Ad, Cell == AdTableViewCell {
    static func make(for ad: [Ad], viewController: UIViewController,
                     reuseIdentifier: String = Identifier.adTableViewCell) -> HomeViewDataSource {
        return HomeViewDataSource(models: ad, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) { (ad, adTableViewCell) in
            adTableViewCell.ad = ad
        }
    }
}
```

I then set this in the ViewController as;

```
func configureTableViewDataSource(_ recentAds: [Ad]) {
    dataSource = SectionedHomeViewDataSource(dataSources: [
        HomeViewDataSource.make(for: recentAds, viewController: self)])
    tableView.dataSource = dataSource
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

What is the best approach to inset another cell type using this dataSource structure?

Comment: Extend `HomeViewDataSource` to handle multiple cell types or drop it.

Comment: How can I handle multiple cells?

Comment: This depends on the content of `HomeViewDataSource`